# Rails output to command line and rewrite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I want to show the progress of a script on the command prompt as it runs, something like 645345/12032451 as it goes, rather than printing the ID on every line (there'd be millions of rows).

Can I do that?

Comment: sure, either use a curses library, or print backspace characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [1,2,3,4]
count = array.size

array.each_with_index do |item, i|
  print "\rProcessing #{i+1}/#{count}... "
  sleep 2 # you won't need this
end
puts "done."
```